# QuestDb Web Console Path for Application Load Balancer

Tags: listener, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer, questdb

I have set up QuestDb pod in AWS EKS. I have ALB to EKS mapped.
I want to know what to use for QuestDb's ALB Listener path

I tried searching it on the internet but all I found was just /
It's not working for me. Any of you any idea what is the listener path for Questdb web UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QuestDB web interface listens by default on port 9000. When configuring the ALB you need to point your listener / to the target group exposing port 9000 of the instance running QuestDB.